# how to do something when an activity finished in android?

Tags: android

In one of my `activity` named  `ActivityGame` there is a number(`int score`) that is changing while  the program is running, and I want to save the last value of this number. In fact I want that value right before the `activity` closed. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: override method ondestroy and write your save code under it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

onPause() is a premature release. You can return the result with the onStop() method so that every time the user leaves the activity you can be sure you have the right value stored. Alternatively use the onDestroy() method which ideally leads to a process kill.

It all depends on how and what the data 
is used for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared prefernce for this in onPause():

```
void onPause(){

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor=sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("key", scorevalue);
        editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Gather all the values on OnPause()

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
              // Gather the values from the entities here.
    }
```

### and Save it on Stop()

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
//Save Values Here
}
```